Grant money not enough to cover project
I am applying for a 12-month long grant that is valued at $100,000. However, this is not even enough to pay for 12 months of a graduate student tuition and stipend at my institution to complete the proposed work. And we haven't even gotten into the other expenses related to the research project.
Should I simply state in the budget that I will use other sources of funding (my startup money) to cover the remainder needed to fund the student and equipment to the full 12 month period?
Or will the grant reviewers view this negatively since I won't be able to complete the proposed work solely with the money from the grant.

The answer will depend on where you are based and which grants you are applying for. Can you specify?

Check the rules of the grant scheme. In those that I am familiar with, co-investment from another source will be viewed postively.

So if a graduate student participates in your project, the university expects you to cover not only the stipend but also the full tuition?

@quarague yes for PhD students that is the standard across US R1 universities.
